# Call angular directive controller method from link

Tags: angularjs, hyperlink, controller, typescript, directive

I'm attempting to code an angular directive in typescript that uses a controller together with a template to display data loaded from a web-api. The data loaded should depend on a property in the controller to the view in which the directive is applied like this:

```
<my-directive watched-prop="ctrl.dataProperty"></my-directive>
```

The idea is that every time the dataProperty above is changed some new data should be loaded and applied to the directive's template. To accomplish this I was thinking to use something like this:

```
module Test.Directives {
    class MyDirectiveController {

        public data: any;

        // ngInject
        constructor( /* Inject params */) {}

        public testMethod(): void {
            // Do something useful and set data-property
        }
    }

    function linkImpl(scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes, ctrl: ng.INgModelController) {
        var watcher = scope.$watch("watchedProp", (newValue, oldValue) => {
            if (newValue !== oldValue) {
               // on change call testMethod in controller... (how?)
            }
        });
        scope.$on("$destroy", () => { watcher() });
    }

    myDirective.$inject = ["dependency1", "dependency2"];

    export function myDirective(/* Inject params */): ng.IDirective {
        var directive = <ng.IDirective> {
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl: "../myDirectiveTemplate.tpl.html",
            scope: { "watchedProp": "=" },
            link: linkImpl,
            controller: MyDirectiveController,
            controllerAs: "directiveCtrl"
        };

        return directive;
    }
}
```

The directive's template would work something like this:

```
<div>{{ directiveCtrl.data }}</div>
```

My problem is that I don't understand how to communicate with the directive's own controller when a change is triggered in the link-method? Is there a better, more "correct" way of doing what I want? (I'm a bit confused on whether i would be considered wrong to use both link and controller at the same time in a directive.)

Hopefully I've explained what it is I'm trying to accomplish clear enough and I'd appreciate any pointers on how to do this right.

/Regards Kristofer

Comment: If I could give you a hint - I almost do not use link method *(unless really need its features, e.g. passing parent elments controllers)*. Think just about the controller and view... just my way. Latest features as `bindToController` and concept of angular 2.0 ... could be an argument.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for taking the time to read my question and reply. As I understand it using bindToController would bind my isolated scope to the directive's own controller and I would no longer be able to access watchedProp, which is referencing a property inside a view-controller (parent?) My problem is that I want to be able to set a watch on that property and also be able to have my separate directive-controller/etmplate to display new data with. Maybe I've got it all wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I've rewritten my code and now it seems to be working, however I'm still not sure if this is the "best angular" way to solve this, but it works and that's what I'm after:

```
module Test.Directives {
    export interface IMyDirectiveController {
        testMethod(): void;
    }

    export class MyDirectiveController implements IMyDirectiveController {

        public data: any;

        // ngInject
        constructor( /* Inject dependencies (e.g. service for web-api calls) */) {}

        public testMethod(): void {
            // Do something useful
        }
    }

    export class MyDirective implements ng.IDirective {
        restrict = "E";
        templateUrl = "../myDirectiveTemplate.tpl.html";
        scope = { watchedProp: "=" };
        controller = MyDirectiveController;
        controllerAs = "directiveCtrl";
        // bindToController <- not used as I don't want to loose watchedProp?

        // ngInject
        constructor(/* Inject dependencies (e.g. url-resolver for template) */) {}

        link(scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes, ctrl: IMyDirectiveController): void {
            var watcher = scope.$watch("watchedProp", (newValue, oldValue) => {
                if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                   ctrl.testMethod(); // <- Calls the controller-method
                }
            });
            scope.$on("$destroy", () => { watcher() });
        }

        static create(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {

            var directive: ng.IDirectiveFactory = (/* dependecies */): ng.IDirective => {
                return new MyDirective(/* dependencies */);
            }
            directive.$inject = [/* dependecies */];

            return directive;
        }
    }
}
```

I wish I had had more patience and soldiered on before posting my question but perhaps someone else will find it useful when writing angular directives as typescript classes.

Edit: one small caveat that I don't really understand is that I can't use IMyDirective.create to register my directive, instead I have to use IMyDirective.create() for the dependency injection to work in the directive constructor...
// cheers

Comment: I believe, scope can to clear its `$watch` byself. `$on('$destroy',` is for your custom cleans, like DOM event listeners etc.